# Javascript confirm message problem

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup, confirm

I have a popup confirm box which i am able to show like below.

But i dont know if the user clicked ok or cancel.

```
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ajax", "<script language='javascript'>confirm('Do u wanna change?');</script>", false);
```

so what i want to do is like this.

```
if (orignalId != newId)
                {
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ajax", "<script language='javascript'>confirm('Do u wanna change?');</script>", false);

If (user clicks Yes)
{
add some data to SQL
}
else
{
return;
}
}
```

How do i Know what the user has clicked??

i have tried this

1. i put the code below in a folder1\jscrip.js file but i dont kno how to call it as i have a used ajax update panel in the page so i cannot use ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude to reference it. as mentioned in the 6th point at this link: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=274

> Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("selective", ResolveUrl(@"folder1\jscrip.js"));

```
function confirmation()
{
if(confirm("Are you sure?")==true)
return true;
else
return false;
}
```

Any suggestions???Thanks

> functionality:

so the user clicks a button called "Save first" then in that it checks the condition "if (orignalId != newId)" if it is true the confirm box is shown or else no confirm box is shown.. now if the user clicks OK some values are enterd in DB or else it just returns and does nothing

> some extra code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
            }
 else if (Label.Text != "")
            {
                Global.logger.Debug("Postback Happ, Label = " + Label.Text);
                Button2_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }

 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { if (orignalCsId != 0 && newCsId != 0)
                {
                    if (orignalId != newId)
                    {
                        Global.logger.Debug("Pop Up crossed1");
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ajax", String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"__doPostback('{0}', confirm('Your Data From iD1 will be populated in iD2?').toString());", Label.Text), true);
                    }
                    else if (Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == Label.Text)
                    {
                        Global.logger.Debug("__EVENTARGUMENT1 = " + Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
                        bool userClickedOK = Boolean.Parse(Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
                        if (userClickedOK)
                        {
                            // Add some data to SQL.
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        Label.Text = "";
                    }
                }
          }
```

Comment: so you are asking the user whether he wants Javascript using....Javascript?

Comment: oh that is just a sample... sorry.. made the change.. haha

Comment: so you want to know serverside what the user clicked clientside?

Comment: but jokes apart... i really need this.. i have been working on this for too long... i will appreciate all the help.. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve. My best guess if that you want to display the alert box on the first page load, then immediately post its result back to the server (thus reloading the page), and use that result server-side instead of showing the alert box at that time. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @BrokenGlass, this is just like compressing your decompression software. Try to format your PC then ;). I think this is called a Dead-Lock.

Comment: @ frederic.. it is not on the page load event.. it is a condition within a button event.. and no i cannnot use it in the button click event as i need to verify the condition within the evet.. ie. if (orignalId != newId)

Comment: @ frederic: sorry i was not that clear.. so the user clicks a button called "Save first" then in that it checks the condition "if (orignalId != newId)" if it is true the confirm box is shown or else no confirm box is shown.. now if the user clicks OK some values are enterd in DB or else it just returns and does nothing..

Comment: @user, thanks, that's indeed clearer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a hidden field, but you would still have to force a postback after the user dismisses the confirm box. Since you will end up calling [__doPostBack()](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.2) anyway, you can take advantage of its second argument to post the return value of `confirm()` back to the server without using a hidden field:

```
if (originalId != newId) {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ajax",
        String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"
            __doPostBack('{0}', confirm('Are you sure?').toString());
        ", yourUpdatePanel.ClientID), true);
} else if (Page.Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == yourUpdatePanel.ClientID) {
    bool userClickedOK = Boolean.Parse(Page.Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
    if (userClickedOK) {
        // Add some data to SQL.
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

First, we compare the two ids. If they're different, we need to show a confirm box on the client and post its result back to the server, so we include a startup script to do that (note that you can pass `true` as the last argument to [RegisterStartupScript()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) in order to have it generate `<script>` tags for you).

Then, on the client side, we need to call `__doPostBack()` to force a postback after the blocking call to `confirm()` returns. `__doPostBack()` takes two arguments: the `ClientID` of the control that initiated the postback (the *event target*), and an optional *event argument*. They're used by the internal ASP.NET plumbing in order to raise postback events, but that doesn't mean we can't use them to our advantage.

Moreover, if a postback occurs and an `UpdatePanel` is the event target, the aforementioned ASP.NET plumbing will only refresh that panel (or more, depending on their `UpdateMode` properties, but that's another subject). So we call `__doPostBack()` with the `ClientID` of the `UpdatePanel` containing the controls we want to refresh, and the return value of `confirm()`, converted to a string.

Back to the server side, the page is reloaded, and our code runs again. Since you implied in your question's comments that if `originalId` and `newId` are still different, we'll have to show the confirm box again, I assume they will be the same this time around (the `else if` ensures that).

The arguments passed to `__doPostBack()` are accessible server-side from the `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` request variables. So first, we check if the event target is our `UpdatePanel`, and if that's the case, we know we're handling a forced postback and the value of `__EVENTARGUMENT` is meaningful. So we call [Boolean.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx) to deserialize it from the string we generated earlier on the client side, and use it to decide whether or not to update the database.

Comment: hi... really thanks for the reply.. i think u are right but i cannot follow few things,,, 1. why have u used yourupdatepanel.clientID.. 2. elseif part is a bit confusing... it would be great if u could shed some light on that.. thanks a ton

Comment: @user, you're right, I'll update my answer with an explanation.

Comment: wow... i actually got ur entire code... now im just wondering how and what to use in place of yourUpdatePanel.ClientID???

Comment: @user, pass the `ClientID` of the `UpdatePanel` that contains the controls that are impacted by your database update, since they should be refreshed by the partial postback.

Comment: can i use a label.text instead of yourUpdatePanel.ClientID as on postback the value of label does not change... also the popup is not showing... maybe there is some syntax error..

Comment: @user, alas, you have to use the `ClientID` of your `UpdatePanel` in order for the partial postback feature to work. That said, you mentioned you had such a panel in your question, what's the problem with using it? It should have the same `ClientID` between postbacks, even with master pages, unless you're doing something very convoluted :)

Comment: i mean i just have the scriptmanager in the masterpage for ajax and nothing else.. so i have put your code.. this is what is happening.. the pop is showing but the postback is not happening nor is the value of confirm going in the label. text... sorry but this is a little over my knowledge.. so it is taking time... i apologize for the inconvenience.. i am posting my code above

Comment: @user, whoops, got it, it's `__doPostBack()`, not `__doPostback()`. I apparently used both in my answer and the wrong one in my code sample. Time to get some sleep, I guess. Answer updated, sorry for the inconvenience, and good luck :)

Comment: @user, also, please consider testing the code in one of your content pages. My mastery of master pages is not masterful enough to predict when the startup script will run.

Comment: rest i think i can make it work except that the post back is not happening....?? i dont kno why?? i changed doPstBack

Answer (score 1):

Use the Hidden field in your page and set the value to true of false once the user confirms or not.
Then @ server side check the value of your hidden field IF It was true continue the process If not use return or exit sub.

```
function confirmDelete()
{

    var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?");
    if (x)
    { 
        document.getElementById('Hidden1').value = "True";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('Hidden1').value = "False";
    }
}
```

**Server Side**

```
if (orignalId != newId)
                {
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ajax", "<script language='javascript'>confirmDelete();</script>", false);

If (Hidden1.value=="True")
{
add some data to SQL
}
else
{
return;
}
```

}

Comment: i have tried this... but the problem is: i am using a master page, this is a content page where the popup needs to be called so the code u have given is a javascript.. now if i put this is in a folder1\jscript.js file, how do i call the function.

Comment: i also have the ajax update panel so there are some limitations on using ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude... as explained in the 6th point of the link i gave above

Comment: thanks for the above code... but how do i call the above javascript function... like how will it know where to look for confirmDelete() function in?? thanks though... wish i could give u more thumsup

Comment: For calling the javascript function @ serverside with updatepanel inside of ur page use  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "myKey", "alert('" + TextBox1.ClientID + "');", true);

Comment: Also read this one, could give you some clue http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=273&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "MakeSure", @"<script type='text/javascript'> askBeforeSubmit() {return confirm('Are you sure?');}</script>", false);
                Hidden_Label.Attributes.Add("Text", "return askBeforeSubmit();");

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question has been asked, but I wanted to chime in in case anyone is still searching for a concise, simple answer.  If you're looking for a client side javascript popup to confirm (yes or no, yes or cancel, etc.) a server side function like deleting a db item, the simplest route I've found was to use the OnClientClick parameter in your asp:button or asp:linkbutton in your markup:

```
<asp:LinkButton Text="Delete" ID="DeleteProj" runat="server" CommandName="deleteproj" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectID") %>'/>
```

Clicking no will send user back to your page, clicking yes will run whatever C# codebehind you have set up for it.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript often tends to block a popup . If you try the approach in the below link you  will have complete control on every single click with in a popup.

http://02e34b5.netsolhost.com/youtube/Zpopup.aspx

This popup doesn't need any ajax, javascript, jquery or css trick but gives you complete control.