# Get values from modal popup in parent window's button click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog

I need to display a modal popup from a aspx.cs page. I need to invoke the popup from server side because before the popup opens, I need to pass an ID into the popup via query string.

this is my code to display the popup.

```
 protected void btnNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string queryStringParam = "some text"; // some server code here to get the string ready;            
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "openNotePopup('"+ queryStringParam  +"');", true);           
    }
```

And this is the javascript to get the parameter and launch the modal popup.

```
function openNotePopup(var param) 
{
    var noteResult = window.showModalDialog("AddEditNote.aspx?Note=" + param, "Add/Edit Notes", 'center:yes; dialogWidth:600px; dialogHeight:500px;');
    document.getElementById("hidden_NoteText").value = noteResult;
}
```

When the popup is closed, I pass a string value as window.returnValue which is captured in the noteResult variable in client side.

Now I need to capture the popup close event in my server side. I can capture the event in client side but I need the event in server side so that I can pick up the value from the hidden field and process it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread that seems to tackle this very issue. Hopefully this is something similar to what you were looking for:
[Javascript confirm message problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949662/javascript-confirm-message-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write you own function on ShowDialog like this:

```
showNotePopup('NotePopup', title, closeNotePopup);
```

NotePopup - id of your popup;
showNotePopup should describe what you wanna see in your popup, how it will close;
closeNotePopup function you bind to popup closing and inside it you can make for example post-request and this way you'll catch on server when your popup is closing.