# How to get confirm box return value in ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, confirm

I know a number of people have asked similar questions already. I've read tons of the answers given but none seems to solve my problem.
I have a form that allows the user to select a file and pick a date that the file should be imported from. When the date is less (before) the last import period (which is a field in database keeping track of last import dates), I want to display a `confirmbox` to alert the user that continuing with the import could overwrite some data. The user can choose Yes to continue with import or No to cancel import. I have tried the

> onClientClick

method of the

> asp:Button

control. The problem with that was, it gets fired immediately the user clicks the submit button and I don't want to display the confirm box until I have checked with the last import period which will be done on the server-side `C#`. I have tried writing the return value to a hidden field like this:

```
if (confirm("This Import Process Will Overwrite Existing Data. Do You Want to Continue?")) {
            document.getElementById("ans").value = "Yes";
            return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ans").value = "No";
            return false;
        }
```

That did not work either. I have tried the solution from here: [Javascript confirm message problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949662/javascript-confirm-message-problem)

Somehow, I can't seem to get it to work with my solution because they have some `updatePanel` they are using. I am using just the `DatePicker`, a `DropDownList` (for selecting which client to import data for) and a hidden field (if required). Please help if you can. I can be a tweak of any of the above or a completely new solution. Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like the form gets submitted once the `button` is clicked and so the value passed in the hidden field is what is used. It is almost impossible to change that once it has been submitted. My observation though

Answer (score 1):

Try this , Its work fine for me :

```
    var c = confirm('Your message');
    if (c == true) 
    {
        document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = 0;
    }
```

You can access the HiddenField in your code behind .

Comment: Let me try this now.

Comment: your solution does not solve my problem. It just goes ahead to pick default operation without even displaying the confirm box

Comment: when did you call this javascript??

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ajax", "ConfirmOverWrite();", true);
            if (int.Parse(ans.Value) == 1)
            {
                Session["msg"] = "Import Process Done";
                Response.Redirect("ClientImpressions.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Session["msg"] = "Import Process Cancelled";
                Response.Redirect("ClientImpressions.aspx");
            }

Comment: the above is what am doing. If I comment out the `if condition`, it shows the confirm box but if I leave it there, it throws an error "could not parse integer...".

Answer (score 1):

Try this..You will get the value yes or no to hidden field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowConform() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }

        var cn = document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value).value;
        //alert(cn);
         var c=document.getElementById('<%= hiddenfeid.ClientID %>').value
         c = cn;
        // alert(c);

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Ok. Now, How will I get the return value (true or false)? Because am using `ScriptManager` to invoke the confirm box on code behind